# How to set a window always on top of another specific window in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a toolbox that needs to stay always on top of the main window, but not of any other windows. So what I would need is a .setAlwaysOnTop(true) but for a specific window. How do I do that?

Comment: Please, post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the second Stage you have to call [`initOwner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) and [`initModality`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-) with [`Modality.WINDOW_MODAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL). Then the new stage is always on top of the other but you can't interact with the parent stage.

For example:

```
public void createNewStage(Window parent) {
    //... all the other stuff
    Stage onTop = new Stage();
    onTop.initOwner(parent);
    onTop.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    onTop.show();
}
```

Comment: That's the thing, it's a toolbox for the parent stage so I want to be able to interact with the parent stage.

Comment: In this case it should be enough to set `initOwner` (and modality to NONE) so the child stage is always on top of the parent.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that before but I was using initOwner() before the parent was showing, so it didn't work. Now I put it in .setOnShown() and works. Thanks!